# Multiple ALIAS GROUP BY issue, returning more rows than needed

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having trouble getting an output that is only one line. The GROUP BY gives an error if I don't include the `TF.Table_Field_Desc` and `TFV.Value` items, but it's outputting:

[image: Current output]

I'm trying to get a result where instead of six rows with the first three columns being repeated and lots of nulls, I get one row with all my columns populated.

I think I need to change the way I'm doing my CASE statements but I'm just not sure how. Thanks!

```
SELECT V.Var_Desc, RTS.Route_Desc, T.Result,
CASE WHEN TF.Table_Field_Desc = 'TestTime' THEN TFV.Value END AS Duration,
CASE WHEN TF.Table_Field_Desc = 'LongTaskName' THEN TFV.Value END AS TaskName,
CASE WHEN TF.Table_Field_Desc = 'Criteria' THEN TFV.Value END AS Criteria,
CASE WHEN TF.Table_Field_Desc = 'Method' THEN TFV.Value END AS Method,
CASE WHEN TF.Table_Field_Desc = 'Hazards' THEN TFV.Value END AS Hazards,
CASE WHEN TF.Table_Field_Desc = 'TaskType' THEN TFV.Value END AS TaskType
FROM dbo.Tests AS T
    RIGHT JOIN dbo.Table_Fields_Values AS TFV ON T.Var_Id = TFV.KeyId
    RIGHT JOIN dbo.Table_Fields AS TF ON TFV.Table_Field_Id = TF.Table_Field_Id
    RIGHT JOIN dbo.Variables AS V ON T.Var_Id = V.Var_Id
    RIGHT JOIN dbo.RouteTasks AS RTKS ON T.Var_Id = RTKS.Var_Id
    RIGHT JOIN dbo.Routes AS RTS ON RTKS.Route_Id = RTS.Route_Id
    RIGHT JOIN dbo.TeamRoutes AS TMRTS ON RTKS.Route_Id = TMRTS.Route_Id
    RIGHT JOIN dbo.Teams AS TMS ON TMRTS.Team_Id = TMS.Team_Id AND TMS.Team_Desc LIKE '%C Team%'
WHERE TFV.Table_Field_Id IN (31,32,35,40,41,42) AND (T.Result = 'Pending' OR T.Result = 'Late')
GROUP BY TFV.Value, TF.Table_Field_Desc, T.Result, V.Var_Desc, RTS.Route_Desc
ORDER BY Var_Desc
```

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that you want a query more like this:

```
SELECT V.Var_Desc, RTS.Route_Desc, T.Result,
       MAX(CASE WHEN TF.Table_Field_Desc = 'TestTime' THEN TFV.Value END) AS Duration,
       MAX(CASE WHEN TF.Table_Field_Desc = 'LongTaskName' THEN TFV.Value END AS TaskName,
       MAX(CASE WHEN TF.Table_Field_Desc = 'Criteria' THEN TFV.Value END) AS Criteria,
       MAX(CASE WHEN TF.Table_Field_Desc = 'Method' THEN TFV.Value END) AS Method,
       MAX(CASE WHEN TF.Table_Field_Desc = 'Hazards' THEN TFV.Value END) AS Hazards,
       MAX(CASE WHEN TF.Table_Field_Desc = 'TaskType' THEN TFV.Value END) AS TaskType
FROM dbo.Tests AS T
    RIGHT JOIN dbo.Table_Fields_Values AS TFV ON T.Var_Id = TFV.KeyId
    RIGHT JOIN dbo.Table_Fields AS TF ON TFV.Table_Field_Id = TF.Table_Field_Id
    RIGHT JOIN dbo.Variables AS V ON T.Var_Id = V.Var_Id
    RIGHT JOIN dbo.RouteTasks AS RTKS ON T.Var_Id = RTKS.Var_Id
    RIGHT JOIN dbo.Routes AS RTS ON RTKS.Route_Id = RTS.Route_Id
    RIGHT JOIN dbo.TeamRoutes AS TMRTS ON RTKS.Route_Id = TMRTS.Route_Id
    RIGHT JOIN dbo.Teams AS TMS ON TMRTS.Team_Id = TMS.Team_Id AND TMS.Team_Desc LIKE '%C Team%'
WHERE TFV.Table_Field_Id IN (31, 32, 35, 40, 41, 42) AND
      T.Result IN ('Pending',  'Late')
GROUP BY V.Var_Desc, RTS.Route_Desc, T.Result,
ORDER BY Var_Desc;
```

Comment: redundant `(` near `T.Result`... +1 :)

Comment: Hrm, maybe I'm using it incorrectly, but when I do this it returns the right number of rows, but all my ALIASed columns are just full of NULL values. All the ALIASed columns are going to have string values if that makes a difference.

Comment: @RussRosenlof . . . Can you set up a SQL Fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    V.Var_Desc,
    RTS.Route_Desc,
    T.Result,
    MAX(CASE WHEN TF.Table_Field_Desc = 'TestTime' THEN TFV.Value END) AS Duration,
    MAX(CASE WHEN TF.Table_Field_Desc = 'LongTaskName' THEN TFV.Value END) AS TaskName,
    MAX(CASE WHEN TF.Table_Field_Desc = 'Criteria' THEN TFV.Value END) AS Criteria,
    MAX(CASE WHEN TF.Table_Field_Desc = 'Method' THEN TFV.Value END) AS Method,
    MAX(CASE WHEN TF.Table_Field_Desc = 'Hazards' THEN TFV.Value END) AS Hazards,
    MAX(CASE WHEN TF.Table_Field_Desc = 'TaskType' THEN TFV.Value END) AS TaskType
FROM dbo.Tests AS T
RIGHT JOIN ...
WHERE TFV.Table_Field_Id IN (31,32,35,40,41,42)
    AND T.Result IN ('Pending', 'Late')
GROUP BY TFV.Value, T.Result, V.Var_Desc, RTS.Route_Desc
ORDER BY Var_Desc
```